# How to do such questions in matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink

```
t = 0 : 0.0001 : 0.1
fc = 1000;
fo = 50;
fmax = 100;
```

I have range of |f| as [950, 1050].

And its used in this formula

```
x = ((f - 50)/2*50) + 1/2
```

and this is further multiplied with this curve

```
m = 300*cos(60*pi*t) + 5*cos(160*pi*t);
v = m.*cos(fc*t);
vsb = v.*x;
```

and then i plot it like this

```
plot(t, vsb);
```

but in this i get the error as
`Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation.`

for this part

```
vsb = v.*x
```

Comment: not sure this is the correct place to ask such question. Anyway I could suggest you to check the size of the two vectors you are about to multiply. They seem to have different sizes... v is a row vector 1-by-1001 but what is the size of x (and thus of f) it should have the same size or it should be a coluln vector to do broadcasting

Comment: Without knowing what `f` is, it is hard to debug your code.